# Vertical align text As3 Label Coponent

Tags: actionscript-3, label, vertical-alignment

I have a simple question, is it possible to vertical align the text that is displayed by the Label component in Flash CS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the TLFTextField (class in the package fl.text) has a built-in property to set the text vertical alignment.

Go to [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/text/TLFTextField.html) for more information

Unfortunately in AS3 labels are very limited in what they can do - you could use the `setStyle` property of the Label to reference a predefined `TextFormat` but still TextFormat lacks any appropriate public properties that are relevant to your question.

So I advise you just to use a textfield as a replacement for the label's text option which you can easily manipulate programatically like so:

```
    var label1:TextField = new TextField();
                label1.y = 100; // any value here for vertical text alignment
                label1.width = 100; // any height
                label1.height = 100; // any height
                label1.text = "label 1 text"; // label text here
                addChild(label1); // adds it to the stage
```

**EDIT:** added `addChild` - totally forgot!

[Here](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3text/) is a simple tutorial about AS3 textfields

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer, I will try to use TLFTextField or the normal TextField class

Comment: 'Tis alright - I've updated my answer because I forgot to include a vital line of code, otherwise you won't see the textfield on the stage.